# Mathematical pre-requisites to read History of Topology by I. M. James

Tags: general-topology

What are the necessary mathematical pre-requisites to read History of Topology by I. M. James?

Comment: Did you try reading the Preface? Authors of mathematics books are usually explicit about their target audiences.

Comment: or you might find it helpful to check the reviews on one of the big online distributor as I just did...since it is a compilation of essays I am quite sure that there is no consistent level of background knowledge necessary, some demand higher, some lower knowledge

Answer (score 2):

From the introduction:

> As will be seen from the list of contents the articles cover a wide
>   range of topics. Some are more technical than others, but the reader
>   without a great deal of technical knowledge should still find most of
>   the articles accessible.